# Set a deep property of state

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I'm looking for a way to set a deep property of state.

Let's say the state and it looks like this:

```
{
  alpha: {
    beta: 'hello'
  }
}
```

The Component has a method for `onChange`, using the lodash `set` function.

```
onChange({key, value}) {
  this.setState(set(Object.assign({}, this.state), data.key, data.value))
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper as per https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html .

Answer (score 1):

For deep component, set state like this,

```
this.setState({
  alpa:{
      ...this.state.alpha,    //this will copy all other object values
      beta: 'hello'           //this will change only values that you need
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why you want to use lodash for this. If you're just setting the state with `this.setState(...)`, you don't have to care about merging the old and the new state.

For going deeper into you state do something like:

```
this.setState({alpha: {beta: "your new Value"}});
```

or with dynamic key-value pair:

```
this.setState({alpha: {[key]: value}});
```

Comment: It will not work if `alpha` has multiple key values. This will overwrite the value of `alpha` with the new object.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Your answer would handle this.